# Creating an array of pointers of classes in an hierarchy

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I have this hierarchy of classes :

```
B1   B2
 \   /
   C
```

How should I make an array of pointers in C++ , in which I can store objects from all the classes?
This is what I tried and is not working:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class MyClass {
  public:
    void myFunction() {
      cout << "Some content in parent class." ;
    }
};

class MyOtherClass {
  public:
    void myOtherFunction() {
      cout << "Some content in another class." ;
    }
};

class MyChildClass: public MyClass, public MyOtherClass {
};

int main() {
  MyChildClass **v=new MyChildClass*[3];
  v[1]=new MyClass();
  v[2]=new MyOtherClass();
  v[1]->myFunction();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your question is pretty unclear, please read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your point it may help us to understand what you want to do

Comment: What do you want to happen when you accidentally do `v[1]=new MyClass(); v[1]->myOtherFunction();` ?

Comment: It is not possible to store pointers to multiple types in the same array unless they all have a common *base* class. Having a common *derived* class does not help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand, that you can store only pointer to child into pointer to parent and only in that order. Secondly, You may want to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), so your code will looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;
class MyClass {
  public:
    void myFunction() {
      cout << "Some content in parent class." ;
    }
};

class MyOtherClass {
  public:
    void myOtherFunction() {
      cout << "Some content in another class." ;
    }
};

class MyChildClass: public MyClass, public MyOtherClass {
};

int main() {
    std::variant<MyClass*, MyOtherClass*> v[3];
    v[1]=new MyClass();
    v[2]=new MyOtherClass();

    std::get<MyClass*>(v[1])->myFunction();
    std::get<MyOtherClass*>(v[2])->myOtherFunction();
    return 0;
}
```